# How can I monitor stack states in CLR?

Tags: c#, debugging, clr

Actually, question is in the header.

For example, I can monitor behavior of reference my reference types during debug session with command `!dso` provided by `SOS.dll`. My question is how can I monitor what objects (both reference and value types) stack contains in defined moment during debug session? Is there any debug utils for such needs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are attached and have the SOS extension loaded then the command !clrstack -p (which is included in SOS) will show you the current managed stack (with parameters) for the thread.  You can run ~*e !clrstack to dump the stacks for all threads.

You might also consider loading the psscor2 (.net 2.0/3.0/3.5) /psscor4 (.net 4.0) extension - it has additional functionality not in SOS.

PSSCOR2 can be downloaded here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1073

PSSCOR4 is available here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21255

This blog post has a nice intro to psscor2 (psscor4 if you are running .net 4.0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/11/intro-to-windbg-for-net-developers.aspx